# java httphandler - sendResponseHeaders: being invoked with a content length for a HEAD request

Tags: javafx, header, streaming, response, httphandler

Im currently working on a simple HttpHandler to Display the content of an mp4 video (in an https url). In my browser it works, everything is displayed as it should, but when im passing this http url to javafx mediaplayer it gives me the error:

```
Nov 09, 2015 10:02:13 PM sun.net.httpserver.ExchangeImpl sendResponseHeaders
WARNING: sendResponseHeaders: being invoked with a content length for a HEAD request
```

Why does this error show?
HandlerCode:

```
@Override
public void handle(HttpExchange exchange)
        throws IOException
{
    Headers h = exchange.getResponseHeaders();
    h.add("viewport", "width=device-width");
    String res = "<html><body><video controls autoplay name=\"media\"><br><source src=\"https://longurl.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video></body></html>";
    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, res.length());
    System.out.println("ResponseHeaders sent with " + res.length());
    exchange.getResponseBody().write(res.getBytes());
    exchange.getResponseBody().flush();
    exchange.getResponseBody().close();
    System.out.println("Sent data");
}
```

MediaPlayer Thread:

```
private void init(String source) //new URL("http://localhost:8000/stream").toURI().toASCIIString()
{
    System.out.println("ttttt T_T");
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            media = new Media(source);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

            mediaPlayer.setOnReady(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mediaPlayer.play();
        }
    });

            root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
        }
    });
}
```

Console Output:

```
ttttt T_T
Nov 09, 2015 10:02:13 PM sun.net.httpserver.ExchangeImpl sendResponseHeaders
WARNUNG: sendResponseHeaders: being invoked with a content length for a HEAD request
ResponseHeaders sent with 961
ResponseHeaders sent with 961
Sent data
ResponseHeaders sent with 961
Sent data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In earlier versions Java isn't able to handle https urls that well. This got fixed since JDK 1.8.0_76. But at the moment there is no public release, there is only a early access build.